# Uso de los ciclos "for" y las listas en python

Tags: python

Quisiera indagar un poco sobre el uso de los ciclos y las listas en python.

Este es un pequeño programa de consola el cual me pregunta <**x**>, (en este caso: **1, 3+1**) cantidad de veces el título de un video de youtube, el cual es almacenado en la variable <**t**>, y las views del video, almacenadas en **v**, y asi almacenar cada uno de esos valores en forma de lista en la variable <**video**>, para poder entrelazar <**t**> y <**v**> dentro de una lista, y que cada título tenga su respectivo número de visitas.
El problema llega cuando quiero saber cuál es el video más visto, ya que la variable **video** siempre toma el último valor que le asigno y no logro compararlo con los valores dados anteriormente

```
video = []
for i in range(1, 3+1):
    t = input("Ingrese el titulo del video: ")
    v = int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de views del video: ")
    video = [t, b]
if video[1] > i :
    print("el video con mas views es: {video[0]}")
```

Aunque ya he intentado hacerlo de varias otras formas por ejemplo:

```
   if  video[1] > video[1]:
        print("el video con mas views es: {video[0]}")
```

De cualquier forma en la que lo haga esto siempre me da como resultado:

```
    terminal/    -----> el video mas visto es: (ultimo valor asignado a la variable <video>)
```

Por más que la cantidad de views sea mayor en las anteriores vueltas del ciclo...

(Yo supongo que el error esta en la asignación de la variable <**video = [t, b]**> ya que siempre va a tomar el último valor dado, en este caso el de la tercer vuelta del loop).

Comment: Dos opciones 1. Creas una clase video para almacenar los videos y luego vuelves a recorrer la lista para obtener el video con mayor vistas o 2. Crea la variable vide9 fuera del for `video =[0,0]` y mueve el `if` antes de hacer la asignación de la variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cant_videos = int(input('Cantidad de videos a analizar:'))
list_videos= []
for i in range(1, cant_videos+1):
    t = input("Ingrese el titulo del video: ")
    v = int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de views del video: "))
    list_videos.append([t, v])
max= list_videos[0][1]
for i in list_videos:
    if i[1] > max:
        max= i[1]
for e in lista:
    if e[1] == max:
        print('El video con mas views es:', e[0])
```

En cuanto a corrección de tu código, primero, la variable de las views la llamaste v, además de que le falta un paréntesis al final, y en la lista de video la llamaste b.
en la parte del if estas comparando el segundo valor del ultimo elemento que cargaste con la i que es el rango que usas para cargar los datos. esa i es para que te pida 3 veces esos inputs.

yo lo hice así..

1. Le agregue que pida la cantidad de videos que vas a cargar.
2. Cree una lista para ir agregando con el .append los elementos como listas también. [['video1', 1],['video2', 3],['video3', 2]]
3. Asigne a la variable max el primer elemento así lo puedo ir comparando.
4. El for para ir recorriendo la lista y dentro voy preguntando si ese elemento i[1] es mayor que el max que le asigne en el pto 3). Si se cumple toma como max este ultimo valor. sino sigue con el for al siguiente valor y así hasta encontrar el mayor. Hasta acá encontramos el mayor pero no sabemos el titulo.(esto quizás se puede mejorar pero no encontré otra opción).
5. recorremos la lista y buscamos en cada elemento que su segundo valor sea el numero que nos dio en el max y lo imprimimos.

Comment: Si! No tuve en cuenta la funcion .append, y la variable max para ir comparando en cada ciclo, me fue muy útil, seguire indagando un poco mas sobre tu codigo

Answer (score 0):

**Entrada de datos:**

Para guardar los datos de los videos creas una `lista_de_videos`.

El `for` solo es para que se ejecute tres veces, no se utiliza el indice, así que `range()` puede empezar con el valor por defecto.

```
lista_de_videos = []

for _ in range(3):
    nombre_del_video = input('Nombre del video: ')
    visitas_del_video = int(input('Numero de visitas'))
    lista_de_videos.append([nombre_del_video, visitas_del_video])
```

Una vez introduces los datos la lista sería:

`lista_de_videos = [['v1', 54], ['v2', 85], ['v3', 4]]`

**Buscar el valor máximo:**

**función max()**

La función `max(lista, key= )`  dará el valor máximo pero hay que indicarle cual es el indice de ordenación:

- con una función lambda.

```
print(max(lista_de_videos, key=lambda x: x[1]))
```

- con itemgetter

```
from operator import itemgetter

print(max(lista_de_videos, key=itemgetter(1)))
```

**Crear función max**

```
maximo_lista = [lista_de_videos[0][0], lista_de_videos[0][1]]

for dato in lista_de_videos:
    if dato[1] > maximo_lista[1]:
        maximo_lista = dato.copy()

print(f"el video con mas views es: {maximo_lista[0]}")
```

Para pasar `dato` a `maximo_lista` se le envía una copia de la lista, `maximo_lista = dato` sería crear un puntero, con lo que cualquier modificación posterior podria hacer cambios en la lista original.

**Ordenar la lista**

En ocasiones puede ser interesante ordenar la lista

`print(sorted(lista_de_videos, key=lambda x: x[1])[-1] )`

```
from operator import itemgetter

lista_de_videos = [['v1', 54], ['v2', 85], ['v3', 4]]
print(sorted(lista_de_videos, key=itemgetter(1))[-1] )
```

***El código completo:***

```
lista_de_videos = []

for _ in range(3):
    nombre_del_video = input('Nombre del vide0: ')
    visitas_del_video = int(input('Numero de visitas'))
    lista_de_videos.append([nombre_del_video, visitas_del_video])

#   lista_de_videos = [['v1', 54], ['v2', 85], ['v3', 4]]

maximo_lista = [lista_de_videos[0][0], lista_de_videos[0][1]]
for dato in lista_de_videos:
    if dato[1] > maximo_lista[1]:
        maximo_lista = dato.copy()


print(f"el video con mas views es: {maximo_lista[0]}")
```

.

Comment: Buena respuesta, algo compleja en la parte en la que utilizas lamda ya que aun no profundice en tal funcion, tu codigo es de utilidad y me ayudó a comprender un poco mas el uso de las listas en los ciclos. Gracias por apoyar a los niveles mas novatos de la comunidad, ustedes desempeñan una labor muy importante en el mundo IT!

Comment: El objetivo era que tuvieses el mayor número de posibilidades. Eso era solo con listas. Pensé en hacer otra respuesta con diccionarios, que también me parecía interesante